# BeautifulSoup: finding tag text with embedded tag

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I am trying to find an `<a>` tag in a webpage by its enclosed text, using BeautifulSoup 4 in Python. I use a real expression, as in the following example:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
soup = BS('<a>lalala <del>10</del> lalala </a>')
soup1 = BS('<a>lalala 10 lalala </a>'
>>> soup.find_all('a', text=re.compile('lalala'))
[]
>>> soup1.find_all('a', text=re.compile('lalala'))
[<a>lalala 10 lalala </a>]
```

Why is the embedded `<del></del>` tag keeping me from finding the `<a>` tag whose text contains it? And how can I fix it?

Comment: **Tip:** You forgot `import re` in your example :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with your regex but the way the [`.string`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string) (the `text` argument is called `string` in in Beautiful Soup 4.4.0) argument works which is that it return None if a tag contains more than one thing. 
You can use [a function](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function) do this:

```
def in_text(tag):
    return tag.name == 'a' and 'lalala' in tag.text

soup.find_all(in_text)
```

Which yields:

```
[<a>lalala <del>10</del> lalala </a>]
```